# Problema con NumberFormatException y showInputDialog

Tags: java, excepciones, try-catch

Mi problema es que tengo una ventana `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` que recibe un dato de tipo `int`. Quería hacer un `try-catch` para manejar la excepción `NumberFormatException` por si metían una letra en lugar de un número. El problema que tengo es que si cierras o seleccionas cancelar en `showInputDialog`, lo trata también como un `NumberFormatException` ya que un `int` no puede ser null. ¿Cómo puedo tratar estas excepciones por separado?

Aquí el fragmento de código:

```
do{
    try{
        calcular.pedir_precio_materiales(
            Integer.parseInt(
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("¿Cual es el coste total de los materiales?")
            )
        );
    }catch(NumberFormatException exc){
        excepción_de_formato=true;
        System.out.println("Valor incorrecto, intente de nuevo");
    }
}while(excepción_de_formato);
```

PD: `calcular.pedir_precio_materiales()` es un método de otra clase y `excepción_de_formato` es un `boolean` que declaré anteriormente.

Comment: `excepción_de_formato` trata de no usar letras con acento (tilde) o ñ, en tus nombres de variables, clases, métodos etc. Podría dar problemas en algún momento. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano Eso depende de la codificación de los archivos, si se usa la codificación UTF-8 no dará problemas, está totalmente permitido en Java.

Comment: @ArtEze Lo sé, pero se recomienda siempre por convención de nombres, no usar caracteres acentuados y si preguntas a los programadores hispanos habrá muy pocos que usen acentos. No he visto hasta ahora código de ejemplo que acentúe los nombres de clases, métodos, variables, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```
do {
    String stringInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Entre un número");
    try {
        int numero = Integer.parseInt(stringInput);
        calcular.pedir_precio_materiales(numero);

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println ("El valor introducido no es un número.");
    }
} while (excepcion_de_formato);
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que pasa es que si haces click si o si necesita un valor tu try por eso te resuelve en catch.
inicializa tu int antes. por ejemplo:

```
try{
 int a=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInput.....);
            calcular.pedir_precio_materiales(a);
            }catch(NumberFormatException exc){
                excepción_de_formato=true;
                System.out.println("Valor incorrecto, intente de nuevo");
            }
```

Comment: es lo mismo, ya probé, incluso intenté hacer un if(a==JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
      System.exit(0);
     }else if(a==JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION){
      System.exit(0);
     } Pero nada, por alguna razón no ejecuta el System.exit(0); antes del catch.

Comment: @AlejandroArevalo Intenta probar lo que respondí.

Comment: @FrEqDe acabo de intentarlo tal cual lo pusiste y me sigue pasando lo mismo.

Comment: @AlejandroArevalo, es raro por que a mí me funcionaba.

Comment: @FrEqDe Lo solucioné ejecutando todo el JOptionPane (no solo declarando un string) fuera del try-catch, pero dentro del do-while.

Answer (score 0):

No existe una excepción aparte, ya que tratar de convertir algo **nulo** a un **int** también es **NumberFormatException**, sin embargo puedes hacer hacer lo siguiente para tratar de forma diferente el **null**.

```
String a;
            do{
        try{
            a=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Numero :");
            if(a==null)
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El valor es Nulo");
           else
            calcular.pedir_precio_materiales(Integer.parseInt(a));
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Caracteres Invalidos");
        excepcion_de_formato=false;
        }
    }while(excepcion_de_formato);
```

Comment: Ya intenté, por alguna razón no ejecuta el if y me da directamente el catch, me sigue pasando lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

Asi lo haría yo:

```
boolean sigue = true;
while (sigue){
    String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduce número: ");
    sigue = str != null;
    if (sigue) {
        try {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(str);
            calcular.pedir_precio_materiales(num);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println ("El valor introducido no es un número.");
        }
    }
}
```